# Simple-framework ignores empty XML elements in list

Tags: xml, simple-framework

While deserializing a simple list of strings Simple Framework just ignores empty tags and includes only non-empty values. How can this be fixed?

I want this XML part

```
<type>
    <inflection></inflection>
    <inflection></inflection>
    <inflection>example</inflection>
    <inflection></inflection>
    <inflection></inflection>
    <inflection></inflection>
    <inflection></inflection>
</type>
```

to produce an array with 7 elements where the 2nd one equals to 'example' and all others are empty strings or nulls. Instead I just get a one-element list.

My `Type` class looks like the following (it is a part of bigger hierarchy, therefore it has no `@Root` annotation):

```
public class Type {
    ...
    @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "inflection")
    private List<String> inflections = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the ***opposite way*** of this helps you: [How to serialize a null string as a single empty tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213382/how-to-serialize-a-null-string-as-a-single-empty-tag/17220939#17220939)

If not, you can use a ***[`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html)*** like this: [Empty entry in ElementList SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581789/empty-entry-in-elementlist-simplexml/21706721#21706721)